# Calculator skipping to the end loop?

Tags: python, import, calculator

I'm having troubles with my calculator assignment and below are the instructions:

> 1. Use a list to create a menu 2) Create a function the will return
>    the results of the four operations in a dictionary allInOne(n1,n2)
>    Sample output
> 2. Add two numbers 2) Mult two number 3) Divide 4) Scalc 5) all in one
>    .. 6) …
>
> res=allInOne(5,2)
>
> The results will be return in this format;
>
> res is dictionary {"add":7, "sub":3, "mult":10, "div":2.5) from res,
> you are going to print
>
> 5 + 2 = 7, 5 - 2 = 3, 5 * 2 = 10, 5 / 2 = 2.5

What should be happening is that once you enter the numbers that you want to calculate (5 and 10 for example), it will ask you what you want to do with those numbers (add, subtract, multiply, divide, or all) and based on the input you enter, it will do one or all of those and should return the value with the numbers you put in the beginning.

What IS happening is that I'm putting the numbers in (5 and 10) and choosing what I want to do with the numbers (add them) and instead of returning the value, it skips to the end with my def again() loop and asks if I want to do another calculation and completely skips over calculating my numbers.

We are told to import our "Mylib.py" which contains our defined functions, and below is the code to my calculator and Mylib...

EDIT: If you're confused about the low and high range, it's something our instructor wanted us to include from the beginning.

**PROGRAM**

```
def again():
        loop_Calc = input("\nWould you like to make another calculation? Enter Y or N. ")
        if loop_Calc == 'y' or loop_Calc == 'Y':
            calc()
        elif loop_Calc == 'n' or loop_Calc == 'N':
            print("Thank you for using our calculator!")
        else:
            quit()

def calc():
        try:
            import Mylib
            low_Range = float(input("Enter your lower range: "))
            high_Range = float(input("Enter your higher range: "))
            number_1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
            number_2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
            if number_1 < low_Range or number_1 > high_Range:
                print("The input values are outside the input ranges.")
                print("Check the numbers and try again.")
                again()
            elif number_2 < low_Range or number_2 > high_Range:
                print("The input values are outside the input ranges.")
                print("Check the numbers and try again.")
                again()
            else:
                print("\nPlease select a function below with the corresponding number.")
                menuList = {"1) Add": 1,
                            "2) Subtract": 2,
                            "3) Multiply": 3,
                            "4) Divide": 4,
                            "5) All In One": 5,
                            "6) Scalc": 6,}
                for x in menuList:
                    print(x)
                Choices = float(input("\nChoose a function: "))
                res = {}
                if Choices == '1' :
                    res["add"] = Mylib.add(number_1, number_2)
                elif Choices == '2':
                    res["subtract"] = Mylib.subtract(number_1, number_2)
                elif Choices == '3':
                    res["multiply"] = Mylib.multiply(number_1, number_2)
                elif Choices == '4':
                    res["divide"] = Mylib.divide(number_1, number_2)
                elif Choices == '5':
                    res = Mylib.allInOne(number_1, number_2)
                elif Choices == '6':
                    p1 = input("Enter two numbers and the operator. N1, N2, Operator: ")
                    Mylib.scalc(p1)
                for i in res:
                    if(i=='add'):
                        print(number_1,'+',number_2,'=',res[i])
                    if(i=='subtract'):
                        print(number_1,'-',number_2,'=',res[i])
                    if(i=='multiply'):
                        print(number_1,'*',number_2,'=',res[i])
                    if(i=='divide'):
                        print(number_1,'/',number_2,'=',res[i])
        except ValueError:
                print("You must enter a number.")
                again()
        except ZeroDivisionError:
                print("You cannot divide by zero.")
        
        else:
            again()
       

calc()
```

**Mylib**

```
# Input range calculation
def isInRange(low_Range, high_Range, number_1, number_2):
    if number_1 < low_Range or number_2 < low_Range or number_1 > high_Range or number_2 > high_Range:
        print("The input values are outside the input ranges.")
        print("Check the numbers and try again.")
    else:
        print("The input values are outside the input ranges.")
        print("Check the numbers and try again.")

# Functions to add, subtract, multiply, and divide numbers
def add(number_1, number_2):
    return number_1 + number_2

def subtract(number_1, number_2):
    return number_1 - number_2

def multiply(number_1, number_2):
    return number_1 * number_2

def divide(number_1, number_2):
    return number_1 / number_2

# String functions to parse N1, N2, and operator from input string
def scalc(p1):
    astring = p1.split(",")
    number_1 = float(astring[0])
    number_2 = float(astring[1])
    if astring[2] == "+":
        add(number_1, number_2)
    elif astring[2] == "-":
        subtract(number_1, number_2)
    elif astring[2] == "*":
        multiply(number_1, number_2)
    elif astring[2] == "/":
        divide(number_1, number_2)
    return number_1, number_2

# Returns the result of all 4 operations
def allInOne(number_1, number_2):
    print("The result of",number_1, "+", number_2, "=",
        add(number_1, number_2))

    print("The result of",number_1, "-", number_2, "=",
        subtract(number_1, number_2))

    print("The result of", number_1, "*", number_2, "=",
        multiply(number_1, number_2))

    try:
        print("The result of",number_1, "/", number_2, "=",
            divide(number_1, number_2))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("You cannot divide by zero.")
```

If you can help, it'd be greatly appreciated and hopefully my code isn't too much of a mess!

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
You've posted over 100 lines of code with no output shown, no tracing of the control and data flow, and no attempt to isolate the problem.  You say that you're "pretty sure" that `allInOne` "is incorrect", but you show no attempt to validate that idea.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** you programm doesn't run because you make `Choices` a float and then checl if it equals one of the strings. You should just write `Choices = input("\nChoose a function: ")`

But still your code has much more bugs and is too messy:

**Second:**

```
...
elif Choices == '5':
    res = Mylib.allInOne(number_1, number_2)
```

It supposes that `allInOne` returns dict, but it doesn't return anything(which is interpreted as it returns `None`)

**Third:** there's a problem in `scalc` function, because it does't anyhow respond to user.

**4th:** Your program will eventually fail if you had reentered values too many times, because when `again()` is called, `calc()` continues to work. This is recursion(and python maximum recursion depth is quite small). You should rewrite `again()` to return `True` if user wants to continue, else False:

```
def again():
    loop_Calc = input("\nWould you like to make another calculation? Enter Y or N. ")
    if loop_Calc == 'y' or loop_Calc == 'Y':
        return True
    elif loop_Calc == 'n' or loop_Calc == 'N':
        print("Thank you for using our calculator!")
        return False
    else:
        return False
```

Then you create function `cycle`

```
def cycle():
    while True:
        calc()
        if not again():
            break
```

In order for it to work, you have to replace all `again()` statements in body of `calc()` with `return` statements (to just exit function).

It works like so:

1. call `calc()`
2. wait for it to finish (by return statement or after it reaches end of function)
3. call `again()`
4. if it returns `False`, finish cycle

After that you call `cycle()` as main function

**5th:** line `import Mylib` should be the first line in your file(just a convention)

**6th:** `Choices` should not be capitalized(`choices`), because it is an ordinary variable, and capitalized are usually, for example, classes

**7th:** there is a thing called *chained comparison*. For example, `a > lower and a < higher` can be rewritten as `lower < a < higher`. Use it in code to make it more readable.

**8th:** `isInRange()` should be finished to give correct result if numbers are in range and be used in your code, because you just repeat same big sample of code twice.

**9th:** Use dictionaries to make multiple choices with `if-elif` more ...uhm... beautiful

```
if(i=='add'):
    print(number_1,'+',number_2,'=',res[i])
...

# should become this
for i in res:
    sign = {
        'add':'+',
        'subtract':'-',
        'multiply':'*',
        'divide':'/'
    }[i]
    print(number_1, sign, number_2, '=',res[i])
```

I think you can use it somewhere else in this script

**10th:** (yay, anniversary). `if loop_Calc == 'y' or loop_Calc == 'Y':` can be made `if loop_Calc.lower() == 'y'`

**11th:** i think you should make number lines inside `try:` much fewer to avoid unwanted exceptions to be caught. For example:

```
try:
    low_Range = float(input("Enter your lower range: "))
    high_Range = float(input("Enter your higher range: "))
    number_1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    number_2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
except ValueError:
    ...

Also as `cycle()` is created, I believe you should use `try:` in it.
```